# error using doxygen and graphViz: problems opening map file

Tags: doxygen

I'm using `Doxygen-1.8.7`, which i have downloaded from official website in dmg version. I'm using `10.9.3 MacOS`. I have installed `graphviz 2.38.0.0 via macports`.

I use Doxygen GUI to configure it and run. Everything works great, if i choose "use build-in diagram generator". But when i use dot tool, i get this:

> error: problems opening map file
>   /Users/pavelantonov/qtProjects/doxygen/result/11-06
>   1207/html/inherit_graph_21.map for inclusion in the docs!

I've tried to change `SHORT_NAMES` and `FULL_PATH_NAMES` as i find in solution from 2008, but it doesn't help.

`GraphViz/bin` is in paths.

There are no white spaces in *.dot names.

Comment: You wrote: There are no white spaces in *.dot names. but I see: ...doxygen/result/11-06 1207/html... looks like a space to me or am I mistaken? Also have a try with DOT_CLEANUP = NO to see if the file is present or not.

Comment: removed all spaces even in path to result and resource dir (/Users/pavelantonov/qtProjects/doxygen/result/15_06_1108/html/inherit_graph_22.map for inclusion in the docs! ). The result is the same.

Changed `DOT_CLEANUP` to NO. This didn't fix the problem.

P.s. thank you, @PravinS, for editing of question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got this message 'problem opening map file for inclusion in the docs', if doxygen is not able to find graphviz/dot in the path.
Try setting the path explicitly using DOT_PATH in the doxyfile.

As albert, already mentioned remove any whitespace in the path to the output path.

Another good idea is to completely remove your output directory, e.g. html, and regenerate your documentation.

Comment: Setting `DOT_PATH` fixed it. Thank you very much, @Jonas.

Comment: You might want to idiot-check yourself if this doesn't work -- I had a different version than what my config file had. x.x

Comment: In Windows one could surround the DOT_PATH value with double quotes (") in order to allow file paths with whitespaces.

Comment: Also avoid qutoes("), it didn't work for me, 
also avoid any space before path and after equal(=) . Eg: DOT_PATH=C:\Graphviz2.38\bin\

Answer (score 2):

It also seems that doxygen is for activating dot.exe space sensitive. Make sure your path is like this or at least without whitespaces:

> D:/Graphviz2.38/bin

based on experience of Graphviz 2.38 on windows 10

Comment: thank you for your response. i haven't encountered such problem on windows 10 but will bear in mind!

Comment: This was not my experience on Windows 7 (64 bit).  Set the DOT_PATH to C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin and everything worked as expected.  DOxygen version was 1.7.3.  Of course, your mileage may vary ;-)

Comment: This worked for my windows 10 issue/doxygen. The newer GraphViz fails.

Answer (score 1):

The following method worked for me on Windows 10 with Doxygen 1.8.14.

Open cmd and type `dot -c`. Then, delete the doxygen output folder and regenerate it.

Make sure you have graphviz in your path. My graphviz is installed at `C:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1`. So, there is no problem, even if spaces are there.

Comment: what symptoms did you see? as you used `dot -c` so that: Configure plugins (Writes $prefix/lib/graphviz/config with available plugin information.  Needs write privilege.). At first glance it looks to me that your problem was a different one than the original. The removal of the output folder is necessary as otherwise doxygen thinks that the files are already generated (due to the md5 files). Note the current doxygen version is 1.8.20

Comment: I was getting the same error as above and I was generating the documentation after deleting the output folder everytime. That didn't work for me. So, I tried running `dot` via `cmd`. Then, it gave me the prompt to use `dot -c`. I used that and after it my problem got solved. I know 1.8.20 is the latest version but I have to use it due to the old  config file

Comment: In general old doxygen configuration files work, without any problems, with newer versions as well.